# I am facing ElementNotVisible issue while clicking on image poster

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing ElementNotVisible issue while clicking on image poster in image section with next and back arrow (< >). Image posters are changing in some time interval like on image is right now child but after some time period same becomes parent or hide and other becomes chick. It changes dynamically.

Below is the code:

```
while(!isFound)
{
    Thread.sleep(7500);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Prev')])[2]")).click();////Clicking on Back/Prevous arrow

    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@id='carousel-item-3025']/img)[2]")).isDisplayed())
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@id='carousel-item-3025']/img)[2]")).isFound=true;
        break;
    }
```

Please provide the solution.

Comment: Hmm. Currently it is hard to tell what might be the actual issue. Can you provide the website you are running the tests on?

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until required element becomes visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@id='carousel-item-3025']/img)[2]"))).click();
```

Note that this code should wait not more than `10` seconds for element to become visible. If full cycle of images rotation is more than `10` seconds you should set more time to wait